# How do I display multiple categories from a blogpost?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've been trying to implement an email so that the email displays the multiple categories that a blogpost belongs to.

Here is the RSS feed: https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/feeds/sns_newsletter.rss

Here's the code I have going to pull in the last 5 articles and display the respective variables in the email:

```
%%[Var @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt, @rows, @row, @images, @image, @categories, @category, @authors, @author, @pubDates, @pubDate

Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("mycontents\Science_News_Students_Newsletter") /* This line specifies the content area from which the RSS content will be pulled for the email message. */

Set @titles     = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs      = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @links      = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)
Set @images     = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/enclosure",1)
Set @categories = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/category",1)
Set @authors    = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/author",1)
Set @pubDates   = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)

If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
SET @rows = 5
ELSE
SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt      = 1 to @rows do
Set @title    = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
Set @desc     = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt),"Value")
Set @link     = Field(Row(@links,@cnt),"Value")
Set @image    = Field(Row(@images,@cnt),"url_att")
Set @author   = Field(Row(@authors,@cnt),"Value")
Set @pubDate  = Field(Row(@pubDates,@cnt),"Value")
Set @category = Field(Row(@categories,@cnt),"Value") ]%%

<h1>%%=v(@title)=%%</h1>
<h2>%%=v(@link)=%%</h2>
<h3>%%=v(@image)=%%</h3>
<h4>%%=v(@author)=%%</h4>
<h5>%%=FormatDate(@pubDate, "MMM DD, YYYY hh:MM tt")=%%</h5>
<h6>%%=v(@category)=%%</h6>

%%[
NEXT @cnt
ENDIF
]%%
```

---

Right now I'm only able to grab the first category listed for each blogpost. I tried building a rowset for categories but when I try calling it, it doesn't return anything on screen. I need to display all categories that belong to a blogpost and have them separated by a comma. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of the common RSS parsing AMPScript that's floating around SFSE.  I think it's cleaner to reference XML nodes via index.

To do what you're wanting, you'll need to build another row-set with `BuildRowsetFromXML()` for the categories in each article node.  Something like this:

```
%%[

set @xml = httpget("https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/feeds/sns_newsletter.rss")

var @i, @maxToDisplay, @nodes, @rowCount

set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/*",0)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

set @maxToDisplay = 5

set @rowCount = iif(@rowCount > @maxToDisplay, @maxToDisplay, @rowCount)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @title
    var @pubDate
    var @categoryNodes
    var @categories

    set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/title"),0),1),'Value')
    set @pubDate = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/pubDate"),0),1),'Value')
    set @categoryNodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/category"),0)
    set @categories = rowcount(@categoryNodes)

    if not empty(@title) then

         outputline(concat("<br><br>Title: ", @title))
         outputline(concat("<br>PubDate: ", FormatDate(@pubDate, "MMM DD, YYYY hh:MM tt")))
         outputline(concat("<br>categories: ", @categories))

         var @j
         var @category

         for @j = 1 to @categories do

          set @category = Field(row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/category[",@j,"]"),0),1),"Value")
          outputline(concat("<br>category ", @j ,": ", @category))

         next @j

    endif

  next @i

else

  raiseerror("no articles found")

endif

]%%
```

**Output**

```
Title: Bee underfeeds eldest daughter, creating ‘nursemaid’ 
PubDate: Sep 13, 2016 05:09 AM 
categories: 2 
category 1: Ecology 
category 2: Animals 

Title: Mouth germs team up to boost disease risk 
PubDate: Sep 12, 2016 05:09 AM 
categories: 2 
category 1: Health 
category 2: Microbes 

Title: These may be the oldest fossils on Earth 
PubDate: Sep 11, 2016 05:09 AM 
categories: 3 
category 1: Earth 
category 2: Fossils 
category 3: Microbes 

Title: Sneaky! Virus sickens plants, but helps them multiply 
PubDate: Sep 09, 2016 05:09 AM 
categories: 4 
category 1: Agriculture 
category 2: Ecology 
category 3: Microbes 
category 4: Plants 

Title: U.S. to outlaw antibacterial soaps 
PubDate: Sep 08, 2016 10:09 AM 
categories: 3 
category 1: Health 
category 2: Science & Society 
category 3: Microbes
```